# Python Django easy-maps does not render Google Maps

Tags: python, django, linux

I am am testing out this template using easy-maps for django but it does not render the map, I also get no errors on the browser...

```
{% load easy_maps_tags %}
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Geo IP</h3>
        {% easy_map "Russia, Ekaterinburg, Mira 32" 300 400 %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I have installed easy-maps using

```
pip install easy-maps
```

and enabled it on settings.py and synced the database?

Any ideas where i should check?

**UPDATE**

now i used google chromes inspect element and seems that there is a bug in the Javascript code,so this is why javascript was not rendering the page....

```
 <!-- Map creation script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize_map_1() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(, );
**/geolocate/:42 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,**
            var mapElem = document.getElementById("map-canvas-1");


            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
```

i am still looking into how this can be fixed...

**FIXED:**

looks like the default template has bugs, but when i used the map.html template which comes along with easy-maps, it worked..

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Geo IP</h3>
        <p>Google Map Location: </p>
        {% load easy_maps_tags %}
        {% easy_map "Russia, Ekaterinburg, Mira 32"  300 400 using "easy_maps/map.html" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Another Question: I am passing a variable from the views app to this template, for eg. {{ city }}

how do i get this working

```
{% easy_map "{{ city }}"  300 400 using "easy_maps/map.html" %}
```

i also tried

```
{% easy_map {{ city }}  300 400 using "easy_maps/map.html" %}
```

and it does not work...

Any ideas how i can pass the {{ city }} to the easy_map tag...

**ALL DONE:**

the context variable can be passed to the block tag with out using '{{ }}' enclosing..

```
   {% easy_map city  300 400 using "easy_maps/map.html" %}
```

Comment: Are you specifying `EASY_MAPS_GOOGLE_KEY` in your settings.py file? You might also consider using django-debug-toolbar, I'm not certain that it will help in this situation but it may be worth a shot: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: yes i have specified EASY_MAPS_GOOGLE_KEY on settins.py

Comment: I'd consider also testing with different browsers. Hopefully someone can help you out more specifically. Good luck.

Comment: i have tried IE, Firefox and Chrome and they all give blank output..

Comment: Check your TEMPLATE_DEBUG flag - it is off by default. Turning it on might give you a clue.

Comment: i have set TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True and still no errors..

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. Digging around in the code I found out that when lat and long is computed

```
from geopy import geocoders

g=geocoders.Google()
g.geocode("Russia, Ekaterinburg, Mira 32")
```

is called and it raises a ValueError:

```
ValueError: Didn't find exactly one placemark! (Found 2.)
```

Hence it cannot find the lat and long and the js syntaxerror:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(, );
```

If you give a more specific or more general address it will work and the map will render:

```
In [13]: g.geocode("Russia, Ekaterinburg")
Out[13]: (u'Yekaterinburg, Sverdlovsk Oblast, Russia', (56.8333333, 60.600000000000001))
```

Comment: You can get the first one if there are more than one in this way: `self.computed_address, (self.latitude, self.longitude,) = g.geocode(address, exactly_one=False)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I see you have resolved your problem,

I had the same issue:
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(, );
**/geolocate/:42 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,**
at this line, and no map with be rendered to my template.

I solved this by resetting my database (running a syncdb command).